# Fixing width of some elements with Regular Expressions

Tags: php, html, css, regex

I'm using tinyMCE for a website, and I usually paste Word tourism offers in it, which create certain DIVs with all kind of widths, while my main DIV (which also contains the `<textarea>` for tinyMCE) is around 550px width.

I would like to use regex in order to reduce width of all possible elements inside my main div to 550px - as someone else but me uses the page editor as well, and he doesn't know how to manually modify width of word-created-element.

Comment: You mean MS Word? Can you post an example of the text you're trying to alter?

Comment: So you're trying to resize all elements to 550px total or 550 a piece? Are you attempting to modify the elements after creation, or before? Do the divs have IDs, names, or anything like that? How is the page being generated and why can you not modify the div sizes before creation? Please post examples as this question is not answerable in its current state.

Comment: You've tagged this question as both php and javascript; does that mean you don't care where your regex kicks in (i.e. in tinymce or in the back end)?

Comment: Hi, I've just added the "PHP" tag, it seems my post has been modified by someone else.

Comment: To begin, a MS Word page is inserted in tinyMCE, which creates a DIV of 600px let's say - but my main div, containing the tinyMCE <textarea> is of 550px, I would like everything in that div to not exceed that size..

Answer (score 0):

With php you could preg_replace dimensions:

```
preg_match('"@[";\s]width\s*:\s*([0-9]{3,})px@', $html, $matches);

foreach($matches as $match)
{
    // if > 550 then make it 550
    if((int)$match[1] > 550)
    {
        $new = str_replace((int)$match[1], '550', $match[0]);
        $html = str_replace($match[0], $new, $html);
    }
}
```

Remember though that...

widths can be in ems or % too
padding and border add to dimensions
floating things can put them next to each other

... and for those reasons I suggest you are better to add `overflow:hidden` to your main DIV

Comment: Do you have an example document so I can see the format of the word code?